# Convert a date to yyyymmdd format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-format, type-conversion

Which SQL command is recommended to convert a date to `yyyymmdd` format?

1. `convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112);` or
2. `convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)`

I notice that if I use the second one, it will append two spaces after the date. (e.g. [`20130705`] - notice the two space after the value `20130705`)

Is it recommended to use the first SQL statement?

Comment: no direct reference to your question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify a length for a `varchar`. In different places, you get different default lengths; as a parameter to a procedure, you get a default length of **1 character** - typically not what you expect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, as [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), if no length is specified for varchar it will default to 30 when using CAST or CONVERT and will default to 1 when declared as a variable.

To demonstrate, try this :

```
DECLARE @WithLength varchar(3),@WithoutLength varchar;
SET @WithLength = '123';
SET @WithoutLength = '123';

SELECT @WithLength,@WithoutLength
```

This is very dangerous, as SQL Server quietly truncates the value, without even a warning and can lead to unexpected bugs.

However, coming to the topic in question, in the given scenario, with or without length does not make any difference between the two statements and I am unable to see the 2 trailing spaces that you are talking about. Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112)) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112)
UNION ALL
SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112))
```

You will notice that the `DATALENGTH()` function returns 8 in both cases.

Raj